# Difference between CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL?

Tags: android, listview

Probably a very basic question, but what is the difference between setting a `ListViews` choice mode between `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`? The Android documentation doesn't really explain much..

From Android Dev site:

- `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`: The list allows multiple choices
- `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`: The list allows multiple choices in a modal selection mode

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` was added in the later APIs (11?) and is primarily used to indicate multiple selections using a `Contextual ActionBar (CAB)`.

Answer (score 37):

Well the documentation actually states the major difference.

```
CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE: The list allows multiple choices

CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL: The list allows multiple choices in a modal selection mode
```

**Modal** means the user HAS to interact with the window before continuing. Non modal, they do not.

Comment: This answer exactly explained the difference and what does the **Modal** mean.

Comment: Could you please put more light on the meaning of 'has to interact before continuing?' What can a user do in the former that he can't in the latter?

Comment: Modal prevents the use of the previous "view" until the user has dismissed the modal view.